# What is causing this Error? Could not find a model type for region Main even using a predefined region

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, web8.5

I am getting this error when my application starts

```
11:50:56.788 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] WARN  c.s.w.c.impl.DefaultRegionBuilder - Could not find a model type for region Main with MvcData MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=Framework, controllerName=Region, actionName=Region, areaName=Core, viewName=Main, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null, routeValues={}, metadata={})
11:50:56.789 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR c.s.w.c.impl.DefaultRegionBuilder - Could not find a model type for region Main even using a predefined region
```

So basically we believe this tag  is not getting evaluated for some reason.

```
<div class="after-header">
    <main class="main">
        <dxa:regions exclude="Hero,Left,LeftNavigation,Header,Footer,Content-Tools" containerSize="${mainContainerSize}"/> 
        <dxa:region name="Footer"/>
    </main>
```

Problem is that this error comes intermittently on some developers machines and not of all machines, some developers have complained of this error especially when the project is run for the first time on newly configured tomcat server.

These are the versions we are using

```
<properties>
    <dxa-bom.version>1.7.0</dxa-bom.version>
    <dxa-release-branch>release/1.7</dxa-release-branch>
    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <spring.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>3.6.7.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```

Here is the  stack trace on server start up. please see the last lines, for the above error. Any help will be appreciated

```
11:58:53.926 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/osc],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.osc.controller.OscController.oscTest(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.926 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/osc/account-intro-test],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.osc.controller.OscController.accountIntroTest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.926 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/osc/sendUpdateUserPreferencesEmail],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.osc.controller.OscController.oscSendUpdateUserPreferencesEmailCreate(com.belmond.osc.model.CRMUser,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.926 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/sendemailtest],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.osc.controller.OscController.sendEmail(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.926 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/osc/account-user-and-bookings],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.osc.controller.OscController.oscAccountUserAndBookings(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,long,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.927 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/osc/account-home],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.osc.controller.OscController.oscAccountHome(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,long,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes) throws java.io.IOException
11:58:53.927 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/accountProfileTest],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.osc.controller.OscController.accountProfileTest(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.927 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/osc/update-preference],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.osc.controller.OscController.oscUpdatePreference(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
11:58:53.927 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/lodgingAvailability],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.pegasus.controller.PegasusController.lodgingAvailability(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,com.pegasus.gen.LodgingAvailabilityRequest,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.927 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/reservationDetails],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.pegasus.controller.PegasusController.reservationDetails(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,com.pegasus.gen.ReservationDetailsRequest,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.928 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/reservationBooking],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.pegasus.controller.PegasusController.reservationBooking(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,com.belmond.pegasus.view.bean.DXAReservationBookBean,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.930 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/admin/refresh || /*/admin/refresh],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.sdl.dxawebapp.controller.AdminController.handleRefresh()
11:58:53.931 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Product/CrossSell3ColumnController//Entity/{entityId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.EntityController.handleGetEntity(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
11:58:53.932 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Product/CrossSell3ColumnController//system/mvc/Shared/Error/SectionError],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.BaseController.handleJspIncludesErrors()
11:58:53.932 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Product/IntroductionTextController//Entity/{entityId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.EntityController.handleGetEntity(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
11:58:53.932 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Product/IntroductionTextController//system/mvc/Shared/Error/SectionError],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.BaseController.handleJspIncludesErrors()
11:58:53.933 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/cookie-notice],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.sdl.modules.Product.controller.ProductController.cookieNotice(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:58:53.933 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/account-register-sandbox],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.sdl.modules.Product.controller.ProductController.accountRegisterSandboxView(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:58:53.933 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/sandbox],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.sdl.modules.Product.controller.ProductController.sandboxView(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:58:53.934 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/account-logon-sandbox],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.sdl.modules.Product.controller.ProductController.accountLogonSandboxView(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model)
11:58:53.945 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/searchPackages],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.travelstudio.controller.TravelStudioController.searchPackages(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,com.nevado.travelstudio.gen.PackageSearchRequest,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.945 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/getRatingTypes],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.travelstudio.controller.TravelStudioController.getRatingTypes(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,com.nevado.travelstudio.gen.RatingTypeRequest,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.946 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/getServicesPricesAndAvailability],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.travelstudio.controller.TravelStudioController.getServicesPricesAndAvailability(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,com.nevado.travelstudio.gen.ServiceSearchRequest,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.946 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locale}/getBookingInfo],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.belmond.travelstudio.controller.TravelStudioController.getBookingInfo(org.springframework.ui.ModelMap,com.nevado.travelstudio.gen.BookingInfoRequest,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)
11:58:53.947 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/Entity/Entity/{entityId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.EntityController.handleGetEntity(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
11:58:53.947 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/Entity/system/mvc/Shared/Error/SectionError],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.BaseController.handleJspIncludesErrors()
11:58:53.949 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/List/List/{entityId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.ListController.handleGetList(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
11:58:53.949 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/List/Entity/{entityId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.EntityController.handleGetEntity(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
11:58:53.949 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/List/system/mvc/Shared/Error/SectionError],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.BaseController.handleJspIncludesErrors()
11:58:53.951 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/Navigation/Navigation/{entityId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.NavigationController.handleGetNavigation(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
11:58:53.952 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/Navigation/SiteMap/{entityId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.NavigationController.handleGetSiteMap(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.api.navigation.NavigationProviderException
11:58:53.952 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/Navigation/system/mvc/Shared/Error/SectionError],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.BaseController.handleJspIncludesErrors()
11:58:53.958 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/**],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html || */*],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPage(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
11:58:53.959 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/**],methods=[],params=[format],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/rss+xml || application/json || application/atom+xml],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetPageFormatted(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
11:58:53.959 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/resolve/{itemId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleResolve(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException
11:58:53.959 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/{locPath}/resolve/{itemId}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleResolveLoc(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.exceptions.DxaException
11:58:53.959 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/se_blank.html],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.blankPage()
11:58:53.959 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/navigation.json],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public com.sdl.webapp.common.api.model.entity.SitemapItem com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetNavigationJson(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.api.navigation.NavigationProviderException,com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
11:58:53.960 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/**],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.PageController.handleGetUnknownAction(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
11:58:53.960 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Shared/Error/SectionError],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.BaseController.handleJspIncludesErrors()
11:58:53.961 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/Region/Region/{regionName}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.RegionController.handleGetRegion(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception
11:58:53.961 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/system/mvc/Framework/Region/system/mvc/Shared/Error/SectionError],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.BaseController.handleJspIncludesErrors()
11:58:53.961 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/sitemap.xml],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/xml],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.sdl.webapp.common.controller.SiteMapXmlController.handleGetSiteMapXml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws com.sdl.webapp.common.api.navigation.NavigationProviderException
11:58:54.441 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
11:58:54.649 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.d.d.builder.json.JsonDataBinder - Creating a JsonDataBinder instance.
11:58:54.674 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.d.databind.builder.BaseDataBinder - Setting meta key to default: viewName
11:58:54.675 [localhost-startStop-1] WARN  o.d.databind.builder.BaseDataBinder - No package root configured for view models. Using the default package: org.dd4t.web.models
11:58:54.675 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.d.databind.builder.BaseDataBinder - View model key name is: viewName
11:58:54.675 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.d.databind.builder.BaseDataBinder - Root package for View models is: org.dd4t.web.models
11:58:54.675 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.d.databind.builder.BaseDataBinder - Init: scanning view models.
11:58:54.684 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.dd4t.databind.DataBindFactory - DataBindFactory init.
11:58:54.870 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7591 ms
Aug 10, 2017 11:58:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet'
11:58:54.926 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet': initialization started
11:58:54.991 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 65 ms
Aug 10, 2017 11:58:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 10, 2017 11:58:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 10, 2017 11:58:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15113 ms
11:58:56.334 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration - Loading Ehcache XML configuration from /Users/Roshnee/Documents/workspace_neon/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/dxawebapp/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache-cil.xml.
11:58:56.576 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContentServiceCapability' created in EhcacheManager.
11:58:56.584 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager - Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=urn.X-ehcache.jsr107-default-config,Cache=com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContentServiceCapability
11:58:56.958 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration - Loading Ehcache XML configuration from /Users/Roshnee/Documents/workspace_neon/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/dxawebapp/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache-cil.xml.
11:58:56.979 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'java.io.Serializable' created in EhcacheManager.
11:58:56.987 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager - Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=urn.X-ehcache.jsr107-default-config,Cache=java.io.Serializable
11:58:57.422 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  c.t.ambientdata.AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised
11:59:00.748 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.756 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.760 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.BaseField]
11:59:00.780 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.784 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.BaseField]
11:59:00.785 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.BaseField]
11:59:00.791 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.792 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.BaseField]
11:59:00.796 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.796 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.797 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.BaseField]
11:59:00.801 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.801 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.805 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.811 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.BaseField]
11:59:00.813 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.Field]
11:59:00.814 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.BaseField]
11:59:00.825 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.d.d.s.j.TridionFieldTypeIdResolver - Instantiating TridionJsonFieldTypeResolver for [simple type, class org.dd4t.contentmodel.impl.BaseField]
11:59:01.289 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  c.s.w.c.impl.DefaultRegionBuilder - Could not find a model type for region Main with MvcData MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=Framework, controllerName=Region, actionName=Region, areaName=Core, viewName=Main, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null, routeValues={}, metadata={})
11:59:01.289 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.s.w.c.impl.DefaultRegionBuilder - Could not find a model type for region Main even using a predefined region
11:59:01.297 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  c.s.c.o.c.ContextServiceClientConfiguration - Discovery service configured https://cis-stg-b1c293-dev-eu-west-1-belmondr7-dev.tridion.sdlproducts.com:8083/discovery.svc
11:59:01.874 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration - Loading Ehcache XML configuration from /Users/Roshnee/Documents/workspace_neon/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/dxawebapp/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache-cil.xml.
11:59:01.893 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContextServiceCapability' created in EhcacheManager.
11:59:01.893 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager - Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=urn.X-ehcache.jsr107-default-config,Cache=com.sdl.web.discovery.datalayer.model.ContextServiceCapability
11:59:02.344 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  c.s.c.o.c.ContextServiceClientConfiguration - Resolved ContextService capability: ContextServiceCapability{uri='https://cis-stg-b1c293-dev-eu-west-1-belmondr7-dev.tridion.sdlproducts.com:8098/context.svc', lastUpdateTime=1489502644637, id='DefaultContextService'} using discovery service.
11:59:02.344 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  c.s.c.o.c.ContextServiceClientConfiguration - Context service configured https://cis-stg-b1c293-dev-eu-west-1-belmondr7-dev.tridion.sdlproducts.com:8098/context.svc
11:59:02.995 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.xml.XmlConfiguration - Loading Ehcache XML configuration from /Users/Roshnee/Documents/workspace_neon/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/dxawebapp/WEB-INF/classes/ehcache-cil.xml.
11:59:03.013 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'com.sdl.context.api.ContextMap' created in EhcacheManager.
11:59:03.013 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager - Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=urn.X-ehcache.jsr107-default-config,Cache=com.sdl.context.api.ContextMap
11:59:03.015 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager - Cache 'com.sdl.context.api.ContextVocabulary' created in EhcacheManager.
11:59:03.016 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.ehcache.jsr107.Eh107CacheManager - Registering Ehcache MBean javax.cache:type=CacheStatistics,CacheManager=urn.X-ehcache.jsr107-default-config,Cache=com.sdl.context.api.ContextVocabulary
11:59:04.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  c.s.w.c.impl.DefaultRegionBuilder - Could not find a model type for region Main with MvcData MvcDataImpl(controllerAreaName=Framework, controllerName=Region, actionName=Region, areaName=Core, viewName=Main, regionAreaName=null, regionName=null, routeValues={}, metadata={})
11:59:04.391 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR c.s.w.c.impl.DefaultRegionBuilder - Could not find a model type for region Main even using a predefined region
```

Comment: The error indicates it could not find a Model type for Region Main, so the `dxa:regions` tag from the Page View is evaluated, but it sounds to me like the Main Region View isn't registered, failing registration or the Region Model cannot be found. More interesting is that you mention it is an intermittent problem (which might mean it is not a defect), not everybody has it and not all the time. Which seems to point towards a environment/configuration specific issue, so I suggest you **edit** your question and see if you can provide some more details about the cases where it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer of the problem, maven profile  was the culprit .

The core-module profile needs to be activated or selected for  to work.

I would suggest adding  to make core modules as default profile or add the corresponding dependency "dxa-module-core" outside the profile so it is packaged always with project.

```
<profile>
   <id>core-module</id>
   <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
   </activation>
```

Comment: As of DXA 1.6 we removed the Core Module from the default installation (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v7/GUID-2C331449-7CF4-4031-8080-85B3F478F700), since there were some customers who wanted to build a DXA web application without these defaults. The installation script asks you which modules you want included, I guess you missed specifying the Core Module there?